# getFullYear is not a function

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to get the age based on two dates: Date of birth and date of visit. Everytime I try to use `getFullYear();` in the following manner: I get the error that

```
var b = getField("dob").value;
var c = b.getFullYear();
```

I get this error in the console.

```
b.getFullYear is not a function
2:Console:ExecException in line 2 of function top_level, script Console:Exec

TypeError: b.getFullYear is not a function
2:Console:Exec
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried all sorts of ways to make this work and the only thing that does is I use `substring()` to get the last 4 digits of the date.

The date is formatted as mm\dd\yyyy.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the contents of `getField` because it looks like you're not returning a date object.

Comment: the dob field is a text field formatted as dd/mm/yyyy
Is that what you were asking? This is my first time coding anything, so please bear with my questions even if they sound inane. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `var b = new Date(getField("dob").value);`

Comment: Are you *sure* that Acrobat's implementation of `new Date()` will correctly interpret the date in the format the OP says he/she is using? :-) No web browser would (when `/` is used in a date string, all current browsers try to parse in American format first, which is month-day-year, not day-month-year, even in non-U.S. locales).

Answer (score 1):

You can check for type of b to be of Date 
For Eg:

```
    var b = getField("dob").value;
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(b) === '[object Date]')
    {
       var c = b.getFullYear();
    }
   else{
   alert("Not valid date");}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you said

> the dob field is a text field formatted as dd/mm/yyyy Is that what you were asking

...and you've tagged your question `acrobat`, so I'm guessing this is JavaScript running within a PDF, not in a web browser.

**On browsers**, if you try to parse a string in the form `dd/mm/yyyy` (say, `03/05/2014`), regardless of the locale of the browser (U.S., UK, Spanish, Russian, Japanese), the browser will try to read it as `mm/dd/yyyy` (American format, month-day-year) first. This is not specified anywhere (certainly not in the JavaScript spec), but it's been true of every browser I've ever tried it on.

**If** Acrobat does the same thing, and you have the text field formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`, you'll run into trouble — is `03/05/2014` May 3rd or March 5th? In the format you're using, it's May 3rd, but in American format it's March 5th.

Unless you want to test Acrobat in multiple locations (or can find a reference promising you how it will parse that string), you'll want to parse it yourself.

If you just want the year at the end, that's fairly simple:

```
var match = getField("dob").value.match(/(\d{4})\s*$/);
var year = match ? match[1] : undefined;
```

That'll be a string. If you want to make it a number, you can change the second line slightly:

```
var year = match ? +match[1] : undefined;
```

(The `+` converts `match[1]`, which we know is all digits, to a number.)

If you want the full date, there are several answers here on SO that demonstrate parsing a date with a well-defined format.

Comment: Only if the user agent supports an input type date, otherwise parsing of strings to Dates is as problematic as ever.

Comment: @RobG: ***Very*** good point, and that support is awful. But given the `acrobat` tag (which I missed at first), I don't think they're using HTML or a browser at all.